# Hide option list if list is empty in ng-select

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I need to hide the option list of ng-select if the list is empty. Now if I click on the select box, or the searched result is empty, then option list with this `No items found` values is displaying. I don't need this feature. Instead I need to hide the option list.

```
<ng-select class="selectable_input" placeholder="PLZ / Ort" [searchable]="true" [searchFn]="customSearch" (search)="searchLocation($event.term)" (clear)="clearLocationList()" (change)="setLocation($event)" formControlName="location" required>

   <ng-option *ngIf="isLocationLoading else noLoader" [disabled]="true"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Loading...</ng-option>

       <ng-template #noLoader>

          <div *ngFor="let locations of locationList">
              <ng-option *ngFor="let location of locations" [value]="location">{{location?.zip}} {{location?.place}}
              </ng-option>
          </div>
        </ng-template>

    </ng-select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[isOpen]` attribute inside `<ng-select>` tag to achieve your goal as follows:

```
[isOpen] = "!locationList.length? false : null"
```

This will prevent the dropdown list to be opened if there are no items in it.

Another option is to change the displaying text itself with something suitable for your application or even set it to an empty string using `notFoundText` attribute inside the `<ng-select>`

Comment: thank you. my condition is different, but I was searching for this option `isOpen`. but now the issue is the list is not closing after selection.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it into a div and use ngIf to hide it in case the list has no items

Answer (score 0):

To replace "items not found" text with your custom text, if the list is empty use [noItemsFoundText] property of ng-select.

in your TS file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {
  customNoItemsText = 'No custom items found';
  selectedOption: any;
}
```

in your component.html

```
<ng-select [items]="options" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" [noItemsFoundText]="customNoItemsText"></ng-select>
```